# How do I add items in the sub menu options through c# - Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have an existing opportunity with some menu items as shown in the below image.

[image]

I want to programatically add the product using a windows forms application.The existing product was added using Dynamics Online Portal. But, I need to do the same via c#.

After searching in the internet, I found out that we can achieve this by using Related Enitities & calling Service.Execute(Request).

So first, I found out the entity names of the required.As I found the entity name for Motor Products, I used Service.Create(entity) to add the product. The product was added but it wasn't showing under this opportunity as I didn't pass the reference for this opportunity.

Then, I tried to find the relation between Opportunity and Product Line Items but I couldn't find any common unique attribute (ex: opportunityid is not there in Product Line Items). Ultimately, the application was throwing errors.

Is there any way we can add the product in the Motor Products programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid you're seeing under **Motor Products** is not showing *Products* related to the Opportunity, but *Opportunity Products*.

*Opportunity Product* is a different entity, and acts as an intersection between Opportunities and their associated Products.

Opportunity Products can be created programatically in C#. Here's how it might look:

```
var opportunityProduct = new Entity("opportunityproduct");
opportunityProduct["opportunityid"] = new EntityReference("opportunity", new Guid("oppId");
opportunityProduct["productid"] = new EntityReference("product", new Guid("productId");
...
var opportunityProductId = service.Create(opportunityProduct);
```

You were right to look for the `opportunityid` field; it's not on the form but it is on the entity's schema. You can check the SDK metadata file for proof.

Comment: Thanks Dave for clarifying me. You saved my day again. I think you have a good grip on this. I appreciate your help. Is it mandatory to give product reference as well, because there is no attribute productid in my opportunity product.

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve these opportunity products? I tried LinkEntities but it didn't work well. Tried with AsscoiateRequest but it failed too. Could you please help me out to retrieve these motor products w.r.t. opportunityid?

Comment: Please could you raise a separate question on StackOverflow? I'll be able to answer there. Comments aren't really meant for new questions and answers. As a hint, you'll need to use `QueryExpression`, and add two `ConditionExpression`: one for `opportunityId` and one for `productId`.